# EC and Beef Mountain (The Bible According to Spike Milligan)

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-play

I was reading The Bible According to Spike Milligan and came across these sentences:

> 15 And God said, Behold, I have given you the first of free yielding seed, to you this shall be meat, but to the EC it will be a Beef Mountain.

Can anyone explain the part about "to the EC it will be a Beef Mountain"?

> 12 And God said, Let the earth bring forth cattle and creeping things, and there came cows, and the BBC Board of Governors.

I'm guessing "creeping" means "timid and cautious" when applied to the "BBC Board of Governors", but I'm not sure.

I'd much appreciate it if someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: In this context, ***creeping things*** doesn't mean "timid and cautious". The allusion is to the serpent in the Garden of Eden (as described in the Bible after God had finished creating everything). Milligan implies that the BBC Board of Governors are contemptible untrustworthy creatures with low moral standards, like that mythical ["snake in the grass".](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/snake-in-the-grass)

Comment: [*that **serpent** of old, called the **Devil** and **Satan**, who deceives the whole world*](https://www.blueletterbible.org/faq/don_stewart/don_stewart_705.cfm)

Comment: "creeping things" here literally means "things that creep", like reptiles and insects and such. This is humorous because it mixes passages from the real Bible with modern terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"EC" = European community.  What is now known as the "European Union" or EU.

"Beef mountain",  In the 1970s and 1980s, a consequence of the EC agricultural policy was that farmers overproduced food.  This food then had to be stored as there was no market for it.  People talked about the "beef mountain" or the "wine lake" meaning the store of food in the EC

The most well know was the [butter mountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butter_mountain)

Note the use of "meat" is from Early Modern English, in which "meat" means "food", not just "flesh".  This is why it says "seed shall be meat". That is from the real bible and just means "fruit and seeds are food". This line is parody of Genesis 1:29.

"Creep" is just a comic insult. He is saying the BBC governors are like slow-moving lizards or bugs etc. This line parodies Gen 1:24

Comment: "Let the earth bring forth cattle and creeping things" is actually an [abbreviated] direct biblical quote, unlike the 'free-yielding seed' one, which appears to be pure Spike.

Comment: "And God said, Behold, I have given you every herb bearing seed, which is upon the face of all the earth, and every tree, in the which is the fruit of a tree yielding seed; to you it shall be for meat."

Comment: hmm… ok, so it went through additional Spikeness to get there;)